# Appealing a denied Google-search-console "Remove outdated content" request

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search, url-removal

Using the Google Search Console "Removed Outdated Content":
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals

I requested the removal or re-indexing of my profile pages on two 3rd-party sites, that I had just removed my actual name from, that were both denied (the request's goal was such that they wouldn't return in search results for me or contain my removed name in snippets or url).

When searching for my name: "John Doe" on google.com, for site1 (made request twice, second was more explanatory but still denied):

```
site1 (unchanged public profile address): site1.com/people/username1
site1 (former page title): John Doe on Site 1
site1 (current page title): J D on Site 1
site1 (words in page removed): "John Doe" (now appears as "J D" on site)
```

For site2, the words "John Doe" do not appear in the page, rather in the url (request also denied):

```
site2 (former address): site2.com/profiles/john-doe.html
site2 (current address): site2.com/profiles/user-name-other.html
site2 (page title unchanged): User Name Other's page
```

However, for this second site, entering any non-existent username forwards to a general directory rather than a 404 or other sort of error, for example, going to:

```
site2.com/profiles/non-existent-username-url.html (or)
site2.com/profiles/john-doe.html
```

forwards to:

```
site2.com/directory.html
```

As of my last attempt, both of these removal/reindex requests were denied, such that searching for my name (ex: "John Doe") will still return both of these in the search results, seemingly un-reindexed:

site 1 still contains John Doe in its title in the snippet even though, it has now been changed to initials J D in the title, and

The site 2 snippet still contains my name as part of the url ("john-doe.html"), even though that also has been changed, and as for any non existent username forwards to the directory (rather than my profile) as mentioned (so from google's perspective, the page still "exists" and does not return an error).

Comment: We don't accept questions here about third party sites, only about sites you control.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine that Google would let you remove pages from sites that you don't own and haven't validated in Search Console, hence the denial. Can you imagine the havoc if competitor sites could just remove each other's pages from the index!

You can make a legal request under GDPR if you're in the EU at
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/legal-removal-request?complaint_type=rtbf&visit_id=636812691350981068-928487754&rd=1

Or you can try the more general form at
https://support.google.com/legal/troubleshooter/1114905

I haven't used either of these before so I'm afraid I have no idea how effective they would be.

Failing that, it might just be a case of waiting for Google to catch up to the page changes. and I'm afraid there's no hard and fast rule for how long that might take.

Comment: The removal tool that the asker linked is a tool for removing content from Google that no longer exists on the original website. They let you do this even for sites you don't own - they just double check that the content has actually been removed first.